# How to get the rendered document of a webpage

Tags: html, wpf, vb.net

**How do I obtain the rendered HTML from an URL?**

Let's say I want to have this program that checks for updates on the web in the form of news, schedules and other dynamic content (*Content not available in the HTML source*)

How do I get the rendered (*full*) HTML containing the full document as if you were reading it through a browser?

The following example is an example of the dynamic page:

[image: This is an example of text I want to obtain from a webpage]

As always when it comes to dynamic sites - the above text is nowhere to be found in the source code - only visible through a browser.

Of course I can download the HTML page using a WebClient and DownloadString ("www.example.com") but that will only give me the source page - the static text.

I want to get the final document, let's say after Javascript added its elements and jQuery is finished its set-up.

```
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Dim HTML = WebClient.DownloadString("http://www.example.com")
```

To access/parse more of the HTML I can also use MSHTML.dll to be able to go through the page, element, by element.

```
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Dim Data As Stream = Client.OpenRead(New Uri("http://example.com"))
    Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Data)
    Dim HTML As String = Reader.ReadToEnd

    Dim Document As IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(New mshtml.HTMLDocument(), IHTMLDocument2)
    Document.write(HTML)
    Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection = Document.all

    For Each Element As IHTMLElement In Elements
    'here I can access things like the elements ids, tag innerHTML and so forth
    Next
```

But neither of these will give me the actual rendered document.

Although I could create an WebBrowser control, goto the URL and through that access the page's content - but if possible - that's not the way I want to do it.

Comment: Why is this tagged as c#?

Comment: Do you need HTML, image of rendered HTML or data used to render HTML? For first 2 WebBrowser control/headless browser like PhantomJS are pretty much only options due to need to run JavaScript.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I only need the data showed on the page. It does not directly have to mean that I'm intrested in the HTML, though it would be easier for me to parse the data (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For web pages that load content dynamically, you have to discover the urls that are being called to fetch content by the web page script. Use a tool like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see the urls. Once you have that information, use `WebClient` to fetch the content.

Comment: +0: while such approach may give you data used to render the page, there is very good chance that final HTML will be computed in browser by JavaScript (" when it comes to dynamic sites..." ) and `WebClient` will not give you that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm pretty sure the OP is only after the content as data, not as HTML that has to be parsed back into data.
_As always when it comes to dynamic sites - the above text is nowhere to be found in the source code - only visible through a browser._

Comment: What you are saying @KeithPayne is correct, I'm only intrested in the data - no matter what format it is. I will try this approach, thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm, @KeithPayne! I've never really thought that there was a program that could monitor a website like that! This is too good to be true! The possibilites are endless. Thank you!